# strptime Function and toggling tm_isdst

Tags: c, time, timezone

I am using strptime to parse a user date input string with the following formatters: `%F %T %z` for the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +-UTC offset`. I would like to add an option so that the user can specify whether or not Daylight Savings Time is in effect (0 or 1), and set `tm_isdst` accordingly. This is important because I later use the user's input to convert into UTC epoch time, and the local time zone offset depends on DST. I store the user's `tm_gmtoff` before converting, since `mktime` adapts to local time, and then add or subtract based on their offset input.

Is there any formatter I can use within `strptime` to toggle DST directly, or will I have to figure out another solution?

Comment: If you have a numeric offset from UTC, it does not matter whether the user's time zone is in daylight saving or standard time.  That matters when you have a time zone name.  Even the hour in the autumn when you fall back from 01:59:59 to 01:00:00 is unambiguous with numeric time zone offsets; the value of 01:30:00 occurs twice, but with two different numeric offsets.

Comment: It does matter to me because I am later determining the UTC offset based on the user's UTC offset and the time zone entered. If it's local time (-04 offset during DST), I adjust to UTC in one way because mktime defaults to local time, while I adjust to UTC differently using mktime and the local time's offset if the user is not in the local time zone. Knowing whether the local offset is -04 or-05 hours in the local time zone does matter for my conversion.

Comment: I'm puzzled.  If I type: 2013-xx-yy 08:31:23 -05:00, it is immaterial whether I am in US/Central and it is standard time or in US/Eastern and daylight saving time; the UTC time is still 2013-xx-yy 13:31:23 because the time zone offset is expressed numerically. So, what are you having the user type? Are they specifying the numeric offset, or is your program inferring it?  You may have issues with `mktime()` et al after `strptime()` has deduced the numeric offsets; but that isn't something that `strptime()` can help much with. Time zone handling is at best rudimentary in C (standard or POSIX).

Comment: They're specifying the numeric offset. However, I am using an if else to convert to epoch using mktime- if local (i.e. 14000 offset during DST), do one thing, otherwise, mktime and subtract the UTC offset. I am doing this to get around the issue of mktime defaulting to the local time zone. However,  local offset differs based on UTC, which would make it much easier if I could simply toggle DST (if offset == 14000 && DST == 1). Without being able to toggle, my conversions will be wrong during standard time.

Comment: you could call [timegm() function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timegm) to get "epoch time" from the result of strptime().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answers given told me a lot about strptime and UTC offset, my question was whether there is a way to set DST through strptime, as my concern was over mktime() using the local time of the system. Unfortunately, there is not a formatter, so I rewrote my code to manually convert to UTC based on the hour offset provided and then convert to an epoch timestamp using gmtime.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonathan Leffler points out, the usual way of looking at the UTC offset in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +-UTC offset` is the offset from UTC for *that* date & time, not the standard offset for the user's timezone.  Thus there is *no* info about timezone name and DST rules, just an offset.

To convert that input to time_t (the UTC epoch), if `strptime()` understands `%F %T %z`, after `strptime()` call, call `gmtime()`.  No need to consider DST.  If your `strptime()` does not understands `%z`, parse the offset yourself and subtract the minute result from the tm_min field of the `strptime()` call, then call `gmtime()`.

**On the other hand**, your application may be attempting to take a different approach in prompting the user to enter the date, time and *standard time offset* for the user's timezone.  In this case, knowing if DST is in effect *for that date & time* is needed.  With various `strptime()` out there, one may have a % for a DST flag, but I do not see one, you likely need to do work.  Convert as above and, if DST is set, subtract the usual 3600 seconds. *3

---

** The behavior of `strptime()` might be affected by the LC_CTYPE, LC_TIME, and LC_TOD categories of the current locale.

If `%F` does not work, try `%Y-%m-%d`.

*3 The *difference* in offset from standard time to daylight time is usually 3600 seconds.  I know of no present day exceptions.  Historical exceptions exist.

Comment: There are exceptions to 'multiples of 3600 seconds'.  Newfoundland runs at UTC-04:30 with daylight saving time; India runs on UTC+05:30 and Nepal runs on UTC+5:45, both without daylight saving time. See http://www.worldtimezone.com/ for more information.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - Bad wording with "DST offset is often a multiple of 3600 seconds".  Meant to say "The _change_ in offset due to DST is usually 3600 seconds - exception exists."  Do you concur?

Comment: Sorry - yes; I mean UTC offset is often a multiple of 3600 (with exceptions as noted).  DST offset from standard time is normally 1 hour; I believe there are exceptions (portions of Australia?) where the difference is 30 minutes, and there have historically been interesting regimes such as British Double Summer Time, and multiple changes of offset (more than 2) in a year.  People are endlessly inventive.