# Conversion of date from human-readable format to epoch fails

Tags: c++, datetime, epoch

I'd like to create a program that converts the date of a specific human-readable format to epoch.

So far I have the following code the first part of which creates this human-readable format and the second one converts it to epoch.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
     time_t timeNow;
     struct tm *ltm = NULL;
     time(&timeNow);
     ltm = localtime(&timeNow);
     char buffer[100];
     strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%c %Z", ltm);
     cout << "human readable timestamp  is " << buffer << endl;
     std::tm tmNow;
     memset(&tmNow, 0, sizeof(tmNow));
     strptime(buffer, "%c %Z", &tmNow);
     cout << "epoch timestamp  is " <<  mktime(&tmNow) << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

So the printouts I get are the following :

```
human readable timestamp is Thu Sep 16 10:23:06 2021 EEST
epoch timestamp  is 1631780586
```

My time zone is EEST as one can see but the epoch one is wrong because it is one hour ahead. The correct should have been 1631776986. I assume I'm doing wrong something with the local time. I've found third-party libraries examples like boost or poco that do this conversion, but I'd prefer the above conversion to be done by using native C++.
Does anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: `time_t` is always UTC, the returned value looks correct to me (8:23:06 UTC == 10:23:06 EEST)

Comment: @AlanBirtles .  From this site https://www.epochconverter.com/, when 1631780586 is placed the it gives the following 

GMT: Thursday, September 16, 2021 8:23:06 AM
Your time zone: Thursday, September 16, 2021 11:23:06 AM GMT+03:00 DST

Comment: Ah yes, eest is 3 hours not 2

Comment: In Ubuntu AMD64 if the system time zone doesn't use DST, then it works as it should (`timeNow == mktime(&tmNow)` is true). If the system time zone uses DST then `timeNow == mktime(&tmNow)` is false. This isn't the best solution, but it could be fixed by `tmNow.tm_isdst = -1;` before `strptime`. See also: [When you use strptime tm_isdst is unitialized](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=185120) and [strptime Function and toggling tm_isdst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277306/strptime-function-and-toggling-tm-isdst)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C timing/calendrical API is very difficult to use correctly (which is why C++ is moving away from it).

From the [C standard](https://cigix.me/c17#7.27.1.p4):

> The value of `tm_isdst` is positive if Daylight Saving Time is in effect, zero if Daylight Saving Time is not in effect, and negative if the information is not available.

Set `tmNow.tm_isdst = -1;` prior to the call to `mktime`.